# How can I change the problem: "select" is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file?

Tags: python, psql

> "select" is not an internal or external
> command, executable program or batch file.

I'm newer to PostgreSQL and I was trying to fill a table with the CSV document, using python. For that reason I created a virtual python environment and, as far as I remember, I changed something in the PATH variable. From that point forward I had problems with running "chcp" , "select" like:

> "select" is not an internal or external
> command, executable program or batch file.

And I can't fill the table. I mean the programs runs but the table doesn't change.

UPD: I added the path to "psql" and "pip" to the PATH but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Is "chcp" the windows command ? please add the windows tag if that's so. Please give us the exact command line you've run and the content of your python script if that's possible, for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So when I try to run "chcp1251" I get:   "chcp1251" is not an internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file

Comment: The problem with running the "select" command has gone. I just rebooted my computer but the problem with "chcp" , though I added the path to it to PATH, and filling the table with the script remains.

Comment: The problem with running "chcp" is solved). The writng was incorrect

Comment: The error means you're typing `select` at a Windows command line, not at your database's prompt. If you don't tell us how you're trying to start your database's commandline interface, we can't say why it didn't happen.